# how to set up a new project from codes checked out from svn on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, buildpath

sorry for posting yet another eclipse project set-up question.
i've been googling and looking through multiple similar postings on stackoverflow but just can't set up my eclipse project correctly.

i've tried setting it up as new java project, link source, played around with build path, but all did not quite work.

if someone can help me out step by step i'd appreciate it very much.

1) what should be my default workspace given that i have my codes checked out.
let's say i have checked out my codes at /myproj/trunk/a1 and /myproj/trunk/b1.
does it matter what i use as my default workspace path?

2) how should i set up my project? i've created a new project and tried to import, but depending on which folders in the path (e.g. 'myproj' or '/myproj/trunk/' or 'myproj/trunk/a1'), sometimes it would show import errors or many red X's.

3) even if i don't get any red X's, trying to right click on a custom method to get call hierarchy, i'd get a error saying ' the code is not in the build path' or something similar.
plus, syntax check does not work. for example, if i intentionally doesn't return a value for a method that expects a return value, i do not get any warning/error message.

basically what i want to achieve here is to set up a project so that i can use codes checked out from svn and then modify it on eclipse and check it in to svn again.

similar postings did not quite help me so please do not mark it as duplicate but give me some pointers. i will do my best to supply information. thanks.

update

here are steps i tried.

1. open eclipse
2. create new java project
3. import a source folder under newly created project
4. project explore is populated, but i see red scribbles.
5. go to project->build path, but not exactly sure what i need to do here

Answer (score 0):

Usually I keep the eclipse workspace in a different location than the source code.
I suggest you to organize your source code as a maven project.
You can start by creating a simple template for your project by using the maven archetype:

```
$mvn archetype:generate
```

When prompted to choose groupId and artifactId type something basic.
Once done go in your src/main/java and copy there your source code.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. is there any other way i can do this without maven?

Answer (score 0):

Your may also resolve the put by just moving the cursor on one of the word underlined in red and chose the "Fix project setup..." option. Then you should click "OK" in the opened window telling you to add your check out project to the build path. And everything will get well!!!